# read from a file that is actively being written to using Java [Improvement]

Tags: java, multithreading, file

I want to read from a file that's actively being written by another application/process.

This code which I found in another question, does the job: It reads a file while it is being written and only read the new content.

The problem that it consumes a lot of CPU even if no data was added to the file. How can I optimize this code ?

- Use a timer ? or a thread.sleep to pause ?

Another thing to add, the whole program I am trying to write reads a file in real-time and process its content. So this means that thread.sleep or the timer will pause my whole program. The ideal improvement I am looking for is not to wait few seconds, but for a certain event to happen => **New data is added**. Is this possible ?

```html
public class FileReader {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        if(args.length>0){
            File file = new File(args[0]);
            System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
            if(file.exists() && file.canRead()){
                long fileLength = file.length();
                readFile(file,0L);
                while(true){

                    if(fileLength<file.length()){
                        readFile(file,fileLength);
                        fileLength=file.length();
                    }
                }
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("no file to read");
        }
    }

    public static void readFile(File file,Long fileLength) throws IOException {
        String line = null;

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new java.io.FileReader(file));
        in.skip(fileLength);
        while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The ideal improvement I am looking for is not to wait few seconds, but
>   for a certain event to happen => New data is added. Is this possible ?

**Best solution : data pushing** :

The application that produces the content should inform the other application as it may read the content.

You could use any channel that may convey the information between two distinct applications.

For example by using a specific file that the writer updates to notify new things to read.
The writer could write/overwrite in this file a update date and the reader would read the data file only if it doesn't read any content since this date.

A more robust way but with more overhead could be exposing a notification service from the reader side.
Why not a REST service.
In this way, the writer could notify the reader via the service as new content is ready.

> Another thing to add, the whole program I am trying to write reads a
>   file in real-time and process its content. So this means that
>   thread.sleep or the timer will pause my whole program.

**A workaround solution : data pulling performed by a specific thread** :

You have probably a multi-core CPU.
So create a separate thread to read the produced file to allow other threads of your application to be runnable.
Besides, you also could performs some regular pause : `Thread.sleep()` to optimize the core use done by the reading thread.

It could look like :

```
Thread readingThread = new Thread(new MyReadingProcessing());
readingThread.start();
```

Where `MyReadingProcessing` is a `Runnable` :

```
public class MyReadingProcessing implements Runnable{

     public void run(){
          while (true){
               readFile(...);
               try{
                  Thread.sleep(1000); // 1 second here but choose the deemed reasonable time according the metrics of your producer application
               }  
               catch(InterruptedException e){
                  Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
               }
               if (isAllReadFile()){ // condition to stop the reading process
                   return;
               }
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not trying to focus on the two applications. 
As I mentioned earlier, the code above does the job with sending notifications. The issues I am trying to solve is to reduce the overhead of the application because the thread is never paused.

Comment: You are welcome. I understand. I updated. Let me see whether it is useful

Comment: Thank you for your answers :).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a busy wait loop use a [WatchService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) on directory entries changing.

```
Path path = Paths.get("...");
try (WatchService watchService =
            path.getFileSystem().newWatchService()) {
    WatchKey watchKey = path.register(watchService,
            StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY);
    for (;;) { // watchKey.poll with timeout, or take, blocking
        WatchKey taken = watchService.take();
        for (WatchEvent<?> event : taken.pollEvents()) {
            Path changedPath = (Path) event.context();
            if (changedPath.equals(path)) {
                ...
            }
        }
        boolean valid = taken.reset();
        if (!valid) {
            ... unregistered
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the above has to be adapted to use poll or take.